# Recover Deleted/Luks Encrypted Disk

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, encryption, data-recovery

I am a new Linux user so forgive me if I don't phrase anything correctly or please be more specific in your answers and I would really appreciate it.

**Description:** 
I was trying to do dual systems with windows 10 and ubuntu-mate 16.04 LTS with ubuntu mate on a small partition of my system. However, I might have accidentally click the second option of erase the disk and use the LVM encryption for my files but I stopped the installation before it started so I thought nothing happened but when I rebooted my machine, it said no boot option was found.I rebooted again using an USB with ubuntu-mate and the whole 500 GB are encrypted so I don't know if my data are there or not (the author recommended rescue disk or Live CD but I don't think this is different).

I followed the post below but my results were inconsistent. Currently, I got to the part using `cryptsetup luksOpen` but it said

```
cannot use device /dev/sda3 which is in use (mapped or mounted)
```

but I checked with `lsblk` and it wasn't mounted with anything. Moreover, as the first time I tried 
this blog it with a different boot, it got to the command `mount`, and it said

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on ... missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I tried other advice to fix my current errors but couldn't do anything. 
https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/how-to-recover-a-luks-encrypted-disk/

I also am in the process of attempting to use photorec and testdisk. The photorec is running and trying to recover files but it seems to break my files into smaller files and some of them I can't read so I don't know if they are trashes or not.

**Questions:**

1. Does anyone know why the results between two boots are inconsistent and how I can fix the problem with the command lines as the post showed?
2. Is there also a way for testdisk to save recovered files on my usb/portable external drive? Will they be encrypted?
3. Any recommendations or things I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress file that you linked to unfortunately will not help you. That is for recovering files that were saved on an encrypted partition. Based on your description of events, your files were saved *before* the drive was encrypted.

**Re Question 1:**

As for your first question, I can't really help much here. The wording of your description of the two boots is a bit confusing. That being said, I don't think this point is going to matter much because it sounds like the difference is in trying to mount the encrypted partition which doesn't apply to the kind of recovery you're trying to perform.

**Re Question 2:**

Yes, testdisk can save on any other device. When you attempt to copy the files from test disk, it will ask you where you want to save the files. Use the `..` option to navigate to the root (`/`) directory. From there, navigate to '/media/ubuntu/YOUR-DRIVE-LABEL-OR-UUID' as the directory to save to (the `ubuntu` portion of that path will be the name of the user account you're running).

**Re Question 3:**

Don't attempt to mount the encrypted partition. Your best bet is to use testdisk to attempt to recover the actual partitions that were erased when the disk was encrypted. If the system started writing random data to the encrypted partition, you're probably going to be out of luck.

If the system did not attempt to fill the encrypted partition with random data, you *might* be able to recover the partitions if testdisk can find any information about the partition structure on the disk. Run testdisk and choose your disk, then

- select `[Intel  ] ...`
- select `[ Analyse  ] ...`
- select `[Quick Search]`
- If that finds your partitions that were deleted, restore them. If it doesn't and provides an option for a deeper search, try that.

If none of that works, restart testdisk, choosing your disk again and try

- select `[None   ] Non partitioned media`
- select `[ Analyse  ] ...`
- select `[Quick Search]`
- If that finds your partitions that were deleted, restore them. If it doesn't and provides an option for a deeper search, try that.

For more specific instructions on testdisk and partition recovery, [look here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).

I wouldn't hold out too much hope here. It is very likely that `testdisk` is not going to find the old partitions. If it does, that's great news! You might not be able to boot back into Windows, but if you can recover the partitions, you might be able to fix the Windows boot loader. If you just want files, you can probably pull them off of the restored Windows partition from the live Ubuntu OS.

If you can't restore the partitions, your best bet is probably to continue using [tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) like `photorec` and `scalpel` to recover individual files. Unfortunately, the names of these files may not be recovered, so it may take some work to actually sort out what's what.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed response. I do have an extra question. Will the file I am trying to retrieve through testdisk be encrypted or decrypted? Can you also direct me to reliable resources for fixing the Window Boot Loader?

Comment: Files you recover should not be encrypted. Depending on your version of Windows, the repairing the boot loader might be slightly different, but it typically means [getting a Windows DVD and running the repair tools](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/).